# Datetime attribute not saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, datetime-format

I have a model that has a datetime attribute "date" in a model called "show." however, when I try to save values for date in a form, whatever I input evaluates to nil. I noticed that this also is how "created_at" and "updated_at" evaluate.

I am able to save values for 'date' in the rails console...

Does anyone have an idea about why this happens? See my controller and form below.

new.html.erb

```
Add a show

<%= form_for @show do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "name", onclick: "this.placeholder=''", onblur: "this.placeholder='name'" %>
  <%= f.datetime_field :date %>
  <%= f.text_field :location, placeholder: "location", onclick: "this.placeholder=''", onblur: "this.placeholder='location'" %>
  <%= f.file_field :flyer, placeholder: "flyer", onclick: "this.placeholder=''", onblur: "this.placeholder='flyer'" %>
  <%= f.text_field :description, placeholder: "description", onclick: "this.placeholder=''", onblur: "this.placeholder='description'" %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn' %>
<% end %>
```

shows_controller.rb

```
class ShowsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @shows = Show.all    
  end

  def new
    @show = Show.new
  end

  def create
    @show = Show.new(show_params)
    if @show.save
        redirect_to shows_path, notice: "You've successfully uploaded a show."
    else
      redirect_to new_show_path, alert: "Show could not be uploaded please try again."
    end
  end

  def edit  
    @show = Show.find(params[:id])
  end
  def update
    @show = Show.find(params[:id])
    if @show.update(show_params)
      redirect_to shows_path, notice: "You've updated a show."
    else
      redirect_to edit_show_path(@show), alert: "That show was not updated."
    end
  end
  def destroy
    show = Show.find(params[:id])
    if show.destroy
      redirect_to shows_path, notice: "#{show.name} has been deleted."
    else
      redirect_to show_path(show), alert: "#{show.name} has not been deleted."
    end
  end
  def show_params
    params.require(:show).permit(:name, :date, :location, :flyer, :description)
  end
end
```

Note: I've tries using "datetime_select" as well.

Comment: can you confirm your `show_params` method contains a `date` value? also, can you edit in what the resulting html is from that form

Comment: I'm pretty sure `date` is a reserved word... could you try changing the field name to `show_date` (use a migration with `rename_column :shows, :date, :show_date`) and, of course, change the field name in the code and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @SteveTurczyn. It still doesn't work, even after I change the name of the attribute in the db and elsewhere, though...

Comment: Can you just change ` if @show.save` to ` if @show.save!` and see what the console says?  Also what is the param being passed in as the date?

Comment: @ruby_newbie not sure that's useful.  The record is being saved successfully, but with nil as the date.

Comment: I think there may be a problem with the date formatting from the form. Add the line `gem 'pry'` to a development or development/test group and then insert the line `binding.pry` after `def create` and `def update`.  Run the development server, try to save a Show, and when the console stops, type `params` and `show_params` to see what the `show_date` parameter looks like.

Comment: Oh, and add what your `show_params` looks like to your original question.

Comment: Can you please post the params.  Everyone has asked for the params, please provide them.

Comment: ok @ruby_newbie not sure what you're asking for. Do you mean my method "show_params"? If that's the case it's there. You'll just need to hover over the code and scroll down a little....

Comment: What we are asking for are the actual params.  You can find out what they are by following SteveTurczyn's instructions above with pry.  You can also put the line `puts params` after `def create` and `def update` and read the value from the logs.  Pry is an awesome tool though if you haven't used it before.

Comment: Ah. Okay, here are the params => {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"ZiLHEGkMS8HSirVbWw4pkProaiVDHWXNrEAHeOyQyzo=",
 "show"=>{"name"=>"test", "show_date"=>"1922-09-09 00:00:00", "location"=>"test", "description"=>"test", "link"=>"test"},
 "commit"=>"Submit",
 "action"=>"create",
 "controller"=>"shows"}

Comment: I've tried a number of different formats, but this is the format I was able to save successfully in the console